# How To Limit Who's Assigned A Work Item

Tags: azure-devops

When assigning work items, I can assign them to anyone in Team Services, however, we only want tickets to be assigned to someone who's part of the project. I've looked over the documentation and I found [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/query-by-workflow-changes#assign-work-items-to-a-team-member), however, it seems to only be for TFS, not Team Services.

Any ideas?

<strike>Let's say that I have two projects in Team Services (**A** and **B**). How can I make it such that if a ticket is created for project **A**, I can't assign it to people in project **B**?</strike>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such settings in VSTS dynamically judge which user is assigned WIT in a project and block to assigned in the other project.

But you can use REST API to [get the list of work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#get-a-list-of-work-items) for project **A** and find which user was assigned to work items in project **A**.

Then [update](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#update-work-items) or [create](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item) work items by REST API in project **B**, before specify the user for **assigned to** field, you can compare with the user you found in project **A**. If the are same, leave the **assigned to** field as `Unassigined` and show message the user has already assigned to work items in project **A**.

---

#### Update:

The drop down list for **Assigned To** only list the members who have access for the project by default. So if the **user1** only can access to project **A**, don’t worry **user1** shows in project **B** WIT Assigned To field.

> By default, the drop-down menu for the Assigned To field displays all
>   users who have been granted access to the team project. This is the
>   default valid users group. The exception to this rule is the list that
>   appears in the web portal--the context menus that support assigning
>   work items are limited to members of the team.

And You can also limit the user name for Assigned To filed by adding `VALIDUSER` to Assigned To field. Detail steps you can refer [Limit the Assigned To field list of names](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/add-modify-field#limit-the-assigned-to-field-list-of-names).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I believe I've framed my question incorrectly, please see the above edit.

Comment: Ok, I added the my answer for your updated question. And the drop down list for Assigned To only shows the user(s) who has(have) access to the project.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the assist, this totally looks promising!